# Is that possible that value of RMSE in time-series differ when I try to forecast different number of period?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-series, arima, forecast

I try to forecast a sales value using time-series model up to 3,6, and 12 months. But, is that possible that the number of RMSE is up and down through out the time? How can I know up to which months is good enough to forecast?

Comment: You should try something first, then post a question here how to get the best data set for forecasting.